# How to save cleartool diff file

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Used `rcleartool> diff -g -pred myfile.xml` to get the file differences grahically. But is there a way to save this diff file? For me the file save button is disabled. Any hints?

Comment: Sorry for the delay: I was at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by omitting the `-g` (`-graphical`) optin of the [diff](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm) command: that should yield a *text* result, that you can [easily redirect to a file](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/redirect-output-from-command-line-to-text-file/) for saving its result.

```
rcleartool> diff -pred myfile.xm > res
```

You could do so from a regular CMD/bash session as well using [`rcleartool`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/rcleartool.htm) directly:

```
rcleartool diff -pred myfile.xm > res
```

See also "[cleartool: how to write the result from command find to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14271623/6309)".

Comment: Thanks, this also helped `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268596/cleartool-how-to-write-the-result-from-command-find-to-a-text-file`

Comment: @Ravi True. I wrote it 6 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the reason the save option is disabled is because the diff tool is also the merge tool. The "save" option is only enabled during a merge, and only when all unresolved merge points have been handled.